# Push to a nested array or push to array based on the item id - MongoDb node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have this schema:

```
...
recommended:{
    type:[{
        movieId:String,
        recommendedBy:[String]
    }],
    default:[],
},
name: {
    type: String,
}
```

from the request I get `movieId` and `id`.
I want to add to `recommended` array a new object if there is no other item with the same `movieId` there already, and add the`id` to the `recommendedBy` nested array in both cases.

so far I have this:

```
        const user = User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:'123'},
            {$AddToSet:{'recommended.$[movie].recommendedBy':id}},
            {arrayFilters:[{'movie.movieId':movieId}]})
```

this will only set the `recommendedBy` of an already existing item with the same `movieId`,
but will not push a new object with the new `movieId` property.
(so it's basically $AddToSet for both arrays)
How could I achieve that? thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need something simple like this that is doing upsert or update for the recommended array element:

```
 db.collection.update({},
  [
   {
    $set: {
     recommended: {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$recommended",
        "initialValue": // assign your edit data as init value
        [
        {
          "movieId": "1",
          "recommendedBy": "who recommended"
        }
      ],
      "in": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            $in: [
              "$$this.movieId",
              "$$value.movieId"
            ]
          },
          "then": "$$value",
          "else": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              [
                "$$this"
              ]
            ]
             }
             }
             }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ])
```

explained:

1. No filter but you can add anything in the initial document filter to search only limited set of documents.
2. In the update stage you use $reduce to check input array elements that you need to upsert or update the value in the affected array element.

( Confirmed to work in mongod 4.4 )

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KK53Sd1ARUl)

Comment: hey! thanks for time, however this dosn't solve the issue because if you assume there is already a `movieId` called test in the array, this quary will add another item to the array with the same movie id, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: udjusted the answer accordingly ...

Comment: Here the original and some more ideas : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69747575/mongodb-5-0-how-to-upsert-array-data?rq=1

Comment: wow this looks really comlex, i didn't think it will be this hard!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand @R2D2's answer so I came up with this workaround which does unexpectedly well for me, since I also need to be able to remove the `movieId` and all the `recommendedBy` with it.

I changed my schema to this:

```
    recommanded:{
      type: Map,
      of:[String],
      default:{}
    },
```

I'm removing/ adding with:

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:"123",{$addToSet:{[`recommended.${movieId}`]:id}})
```

And

```
User.findByIdAndUpdate({_id:"123",{$unset:{[`recommended.${movieId}`]:""}})
```